# select option multiple value extraction

Tags: javascript, html-select, dropdown, selectedindex

Simplified HTML (it's a long list):

```
    <select id="tz" name="tz">
      <option timeZoneId="30" useDaylightTime="1" value="0">(GMT+00:00) Greenwich Mean Time : Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London</option>
      <option timeZoneId="1" useDaylightTime="0" value="-12">(GMT-12:00) International Date Line West</option>
      <option timeZoneId="2" useDaylightTime="0" value="-11">(GMT-11:00) Midway Island, Samoa</option>
    </select>
```

For each time zone I have a range of values. I want each of the values to save to a hidden form entry as I want to save the time zone, whether they use Daylight Time or not and the possible country/city indicator and the time offset - four things.

Hidden form entry (visible for now):

```
    <input type="text" name="timeZone" id="timeZone" placeholder="Time Zone">
    <input type="text" name="offset" id="offset" placeholder="Time offset">
```

I can get one - the value (voffset) using this code:

```
    <script>
      document.getElementById("tz").addEventListener('input',MessageUpdate);

      function MessageUpdate() {
        vtimeZone = tz.options[tz.selectedIndex].timeZoneId;
        voffset = tz.options[tz.selectedIndex].value;

        // go plant recEmail and proEmail into hidden fields 
        var mymodal = $('#updateModalt');
        mymodal.find('.modal-body input#timeZone').val(vtimeZone);
        mymodal.find('.modal-body input#offset').val(voffset);
      }
    </script>
```

I have tried all sorts of variations to get timeZoneId to no avail. Both value('timeZoneId') attr('timeZoneId').

In summary this works:

```
    voffset = tz.options[tz.selectedIndex].value;
```

I feel I am close as this produces no value and no error:

```
    vtimeZone = tz.options[tz.selectedIndex].timeZoneId;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're guessing a bit here.

Firstly, there's no error becuase all you're doing is calling a property that isn't defined. That, in JavaScript, won't produce an error.

Secondly, `val('timeZoneId')` (assume you meant this, not `value()`, which is not a native or jQuery method) will *set* a `value` property, not *retrieve* anything (attribute, value, or otherwise. [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/val/).)

Firstly, change your HTML to use data attributes.

```
<option
    data-timeZoneId="30"
    data-useDaylightTime="1"
    value="0"
>
    (GMT+00:00) Greenwich Mean Time : Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London
</option>
```

Then in your JS reference them via `getAttribute()`:

```
document.querySelector('#tz').addEventListener('input', evt => {
    let
    opt = evt.target.options[evt.target.selectedIndex],
    vtimeZone = opt.getAttribute('data-timeZoneID'), // <--
    voffset = opt.value;
    ;
    //etc...
});
```

Comment: Thanking you. I could find nothing on how to do this. A great help

Comment: Welcome. Incidentally, your edit was rejected because your changes would have converted my local-scope variables to global variables. The comma approach, prefixed by a single `let` (or, previously, `var`), ensures they are all local in scope.